# Elastic-Beanstalk: How to find the S3 Bucket From the EB Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I'm interested in creating a backup of the current application as an application version. As a result I'd like to try and track down the S3 Bucket where the App Versions are saved to save a new file to that location.

Does anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this:

1. Get the Instance Id
2. Get the environment Id.
3. Get the App Name
4. Get the App Versions

The data is in the response of the App Versions.

Based on the above, here is my entire backup script. It will figure out steps 1-4 above, then zip up the current app directory, send it to S3, and create a new app version based on it.

```bash
#/bin/bash
EC2_INSTANCE_ID="`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id || die \"wget instance-id has failed: $?\"`"
test -n "$EC2_INSTANCE_ID" || die 'cannot obtain instance-id'
EC2_AVAIL_ZONE="`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone || die \"wget availability-zone has failed: $?\"`"
test -n "$EC2_AVAIL_ZONE" || die 'cannot obtain availability-zone'
EC2_REGION="`echo \"$EC2_AVAIL_ZONE\" | sed -e 's:\([0-9][0-9]*\)[a-z]*\$:\\1:'`"
EB_ENV_ID="`aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $EC2_INSTANCE_ID --region $EC2_REGION | grep -B 1  \"elasticbeanstalk:environment-id\" | grep -Po '\"Value\":\\s+\"[^\"]+\"' | cut -d':' -f 2 | grep -Po '[^\"]+'`"
EB_APP_NAME="`aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --environment-id $EB_ENV_ID --region $EC2_REGION | grep 'ApplicationName' | cut -d':' -f 2 | grep -Po '[^\\",]+'`"
EB_BUCKET_NAME="`aws elasticbeanstalk describe-application-versions --application-name $EB_APP_NAME --region $EC2_REGION | grep -m 1 'S3Bucket' | cut -d':' -f 2  | grep -Po '[^\", ]+'`"
DATE=$(date -d "today" +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
FILENAME=application.$DATE.zip


cd /var/app/current
sudo -u webapp zip -r -J /tmp/$FILENAME *
sudo mv /tmp/$FILENAME ~/.
sudo chmod 755 ~/$FILENAME
cd ~
aws s3 cp $FILENAME s3://$EB_BUCKET_NAME/
rm -f ~/$FILENAME
aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name $EB_APP_NAME --version-label "$DATE-$FILENAME" --description "Auto-Save $DATE" --source-bundle S3Bucket="$EB_BUCKET_NAME",S3Key="$FILENAME" --no-auto-create-application --region $EC2_REGION
```

Comment: You can find the instance id and region in a single document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-identity-documents.html#instance-identity-signatures

Answer (score 0):

tldr: most probably you want

```
jq -r '..|.url?' /etc/elasticbeanstalk/metadata-cache | grep -oP '//\K(.*)(?=\.s3)
```

Detailed version:

Add to any of your `.ebextensions`

```
packages: 
  yum:
    jq: []
```

(assuming you are using Amazon Linux or Centos)
and run

```
export BUCKET="$(jq -r '..|.url?' /etc/elasticbeanstalk/metadata-cache | grep -oP '//\K(.*)(?=\.s3)' || sudo !!)"
echo bucketname: $BUCKET
```

then full s3 path would be accessible at

```
bash -c 'source /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties; echo s3:\\${BUCKET} -r ${region:-eu-east-3}'
```